# How do I avoid deformations while rendering?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, subdivision-surface

After adding some dunes to my scene, I realized after rendering, it shows polygons as if they were deformed. I tried to "smooth shade" but it didn't work. I also tried to apply subdivision surface, tried with all layers up to x4 to make sure it goes away, but it still doesn't.

Take a look at the images below:
[image]
See all the polygon changes on top of the dunes?

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Seems to be a dupli of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/195970/fixing-shadows-in-cycles-without-increasing-subdivision/195987#195987

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91913/some-areas-of-the-mesh-are-dark https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/how-to-avoid-terminator-artifacts-while-still-using-smooth-shading-and-the-new-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under *Object Properties > Shading >* **Shadow Terminator Offset**

[image]

Comment: Hi, unfortunately that doesn't work for me. It has a value between 0.00 and 1.00, and I tried them all and no changes, the distortion is still there.

Comment: It kidna makes things worse because it creates polygons everywhere now, not as exacerbated as before, but it multiplies them

Comment: HI! I found the solution to this, by going to Modifiers > Smooth > play with it and smooth it until it gets rid of the triangles. So, it wasn't a shadow issue, but rather a mesh issue. Thanks for the help though! I will accept the answer above as the answer to my question in order to close the thread. Thanks!

Comment: When I saw your first image I was thinking it is a geometry, but since you said you used high subdiv I abandoned this thought. BTW The proper way would be to answer by your self :) and ask moderator to reopen, now it is referring to a wrong topic. Or ... rather than this "cirkus" may I ask you to delete your question? Thank you